# How to change the ApplicationId of a Website

Tags: iis-6

We have a small webserver farm with one distributed asp.net website. We use SqlSessionState which needs the ApplicationId to be the same on all Webservers. Otherwise Users hopping from one webserver to another will be given a new Session (but remain authenticted).

Ho can I synchronize the **ApplicationId** from the website across all webservers (ideally without creating new Websites)